# How to check if an integer value of a variable is increasing?

Tags: variables, lua

How to check if an integer value of a variable is increasing?

example if the value of positionX is increased, then it reduces the value

Comment: what would increase that value? as is your question doesn't make sense. you should provide more context. which values are you talking about? wha tis positionX? what is value? if you want to compare to values you can do that using relational operators.

Comment: I mean that if an integer value is increasing, be it +1, +50 or any other number as long as it is increasing, it returns true -

Comment: I know what it means if a value increases... where should that changed value come from? is there some user input or what?

Comment: in a game this getting the mouse coordinates then I want to do if the mouse is moved to the right then the value of the coordinates change to the left that would be reducing the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variable to store the last mouse coordinate in.

Then everytime you check if the mouse coordinate, compare it with the last value and then update the last value.

Something like

```
local lastCoord 

local coord = GetMouseCoord()
if lastCoord and coord.x > lastCoord.x then
  print("x increased")
end
lastCoord = coord
```